# How to decompress only a portion of a file?

Tags: gzip

I have a large, repetitive text file. It compresses very well - it's about 3MB compressed. However, if decompressed, it takes 1.7GB. Since it's repetitive, I only need a fraction of the output to check the contents of the file.

It was compressed using `gzip`. Does `gunzip` provides any way to only decompress the first few megs of a file?

Comment: Duplicate, but on other StackExchange site - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676116/is-partial-gz-decompression-possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could decompress to standard output and feed it through something like `head` to only capture a bit of it:

```
gunzip -c file.gz | head -c 20M >file.part
```

The `-c` flag to `head` requires the `head` implementation that is provided by GNU coreutils.

`dd` may also be used:

```
gunzip -c file.gz | dd of=file.part bs=1M count=20
```

Both of these pipelines will copy the first 20 MiB of the uncompressed file to `file.part`.

Comment: What if I wanted to skip decompressing the first x bytes and decomporess e.g. the last 20M to check the tail looks fine? I could just use `tail -c 20M`, but that would end up decompressing the entire file and just throwing away everything except the last 20M.

Comment: @Timo You can't generally start decompressing a compressed file in the middle. If this is something that is really important to you, you may want to ask a separate question about it.

Comment: Yeah, so it seems. Perhaps not worth a separate question as it seems rather grim on this department. Gotta compress in smalle chunks to begin with or ditch compression altogether. Thanks anyways.